# Error while running "ember test" inside ember addon - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Ember.View.extend')

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars, ember-cli-addons

I am getting this error "**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Ember.View.extend')**" when I run "ember test" inside my ember addon project.Used ember versions are as follows

Ember CLI Version : 1.13.1

Ember Version : 2.6.0

Ember CLI Qunit : 0.3.15.

I haven't used ember-data. 
Does the problem arise due to ember-cli version? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating ember-qunit version in bower.json from 0.4.1 to 0.4.9 solves the error.